# How to make an offer code field within a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

http://jsfiddle.net/GZYKQ/

How would I make it so that when the user inputs "DISCOUNT10" (in capitals or lowercase) the jquery script takes 10% off the repair price? Not the total price, the repair price which is at the top of the form (var price).

The script should then add the repair price (minus the 10%), the outward postage price, and the return postage price and display the total.

I have no experience with jQuery so this code probably has a lot wrong with it but this is what I have:

```
$("button.offerapply").click(function() {
if (("input[name='offercode']").val = "DISCOUNT10"){
    price = (price/100)*90;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, your button isn't firing because you're targetting the class of `offerapply`, when it should be the ID, change to `$("#offerapply").click(....`

Comment: Ok I have changed that but dreamweaver is still saying there's a problem with code :-/

Comment: I would recommend applying the actual discounts server side (if you're just using JS to display it that'll be fine), since anyone can manipulate your JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an extra `=`. Right now, you have an assignment. You want to compare the two values. The comparison operator is `==`.

Try this:

```
$("button#offerapply").click(function() {
if ($("input[name='offercode']").val() == "DISCOUNT10"){
   price = (price/100)*90;
   $('.tot_price').html('£' + price);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding .toLowerCase(); after .val() and compare with "discount10"

Comment: Ok I have updated with your code but still no good :-( http://jsfiddle.net/PsRKq/

Comment: You are still missing $ in front of "input[name='offercode']". I would change it so:

`if ($("input[name='offercode']").val().toLowerCase(); == "discount10"){...}`

Comment: @rgoraya that seems to break the whole thing. Maybe I'm implementing it wrong? Could you show me in the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PsRKq/1/

Comment: @Huy I accepted LightStyles's answer as he produced the working fiddle :-P

Comment: @Chris remove the semicolon in rgoraya's code. `if ($("input[name='offercode']").val().toLowerCase() == "discount10")` Keep in mind though that with this code, if a user enters `discount10` (no caps), the coupon code would still work.

Comment: @LightStyle is there a reason why they shouldn't be case-insensitive? And they seem to want it that way. Huy, thanks for catching that semicolon :)

Comment: @LightStyle Take a look at the if statement we corrected earlier. What we basically did was took the user input `$("input[name='offercode']").val()` and then we lowercased all the letters `toLowerCase()`. We take this lowercased version and check to see if it matches `discount10`. The case no longer matter since we lowercase everything.

Comment: I understood the behaviour of the code, I don't understand *why* a promotion code should be case insensitive, not why your script reads in a case insensitive way :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#offerapply").click(function() {
    if ($("#offercode").val() === "DISCOUNT10"){ //offercode is an id, not a name
         price = (price / 10) * 9;
         $('.tot_price').html('£' + price);
    }
}
```

Notice that `offercode` is the ID of the input, not the name([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PsRKq/1/)).

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed that. Anyway using IDs is more recommendable than names. There is a working fiddle in the edited answer anyway

Comment: As @FDL suggested in the question's comments, you should separate the discount and apply it server side, not client side, since everyone can read it.

Comment: Thanks this script is just for displaying the total price, not for sending the total price to the server

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your jsfiddle I would probably take

```
var tot_price = price + postage_out + postage_in;
```

and change it to have another variable:

```
var tot_price = (multiplier * price) + postage_out + postage_in;
```

multiplier would default to 1 and can change to say .90 if they enter the discount on the apply button.

http://jsfiddle.net/GZYKQ/3/

Answer (score 0):

You're also missing the jQuery call in front of the input reference:

if ($("input[name='offercode']").val == "DISCOUNT10"){